# How to implement UITableView like scrolling and cell tapping behavior?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In UITableView, you can tap and hold on a table cell and cancels the tap and continue on with scrolling if you move your finger.  How can this done with UIScrollView with a subview? I am able to make it so you can scroll and you can tap on the subview, but am having issue with the latter behavior - make scrollview continue to scroll if you move your finger while tapping and holding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the subview.  The scroll view uses a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` for scrolling.  You simply need to tell the tap recognizer not to recognize unless the pan recognizer fails.

If you are targetting iOS 5, this is very easy:

```
[self.tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

If you are targetting an older version of iOS, older versions of `UIScrollView` don't have the `panGestureRecognizer` property.  Instead you have to search through the scroll view's `gestureRecognizers` array:

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in self.scrollView.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([recognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]])
        [self.tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:recognizer];
}
```

Comment: I find that I didn't have to call requireGestureRecognizerToFail and the panning of the scroll view still works.  Any idea when this call is needed?